# Upgrading to JUnit4 and keeping legacy JUnit 3 tests and test suites by running them together

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, backwards-compatibility, junit4

I was surprised not to find the answer so far. If I am missing something basic I will be more than happy to know that.

There is a large legacy code base that was upgraded to Java 6 (from 1.4). Large number of JUnit 3 tests are present in the code and are organized into test suite that runs successfully with JUnit 4 default runner in Eclipse.

Now, I am adding new tests that are pure JUnit 4 tests (annotations, no TestCase, etc.). What would be a way of running both old JUnit 3 test suite and new JUnit 4 tests together?

Comment: I would answer that we do this with an AntTask, but I think you mean Eclipse only.  If so, please tag for eclipse.

Comment: @shoover - No, I don't mean Eclipse only. I am looking for generic solution that would run tests with java only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use 'JUnit4' test runner in your run configuration.

JUnit4 binaries have a backward compatibility layer that allows it to have both JUnit3 and JUnit4 style classes in the same test suite.

For command line builds just use JUnit4 jars instead of JUnit3.

This was done specifically to ease migration that you are doing now.

Also, it works fine in my project.

Comment: Alex, thank u, but I was looking for more concrete solution - thanks to ur answer I believe I came up with one. I'll add it as an answer and will give u a credit for it.

Comment: Can you check this issue? I am not sure how to `configure` Junit4 vs Junit3. (Here) [http://stackoverflow.com/q/26848673/668650] is the issue.

Answer (score 10):

The *@RunWith(Suite.class)* gives me opportunity to combine both JUnit 4 and JUnit 3 tests and test cases together:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    ExampleOfJunit3TestSuite.class, 
    ExampleOfJUnit3TestCase.class, 
    ExampleOfJUnit4TestSuite.class,
    ExampleOfJUnit4TestCase.class})   
public class BothJUnit4and3TestSuite {
}
```

The *BothJUnit4and3TestSuite* runs all tests and test suites listed in *@Suite.SuiteClasses*.